# WPF MVVM Binding Text of TextBlock to ObservableCollection Member

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, observablecollection

I would like to bind the value of an ObservableCollection to the "Text" of TextBlock in WindowMain.  The DataContext of WindowMain points to its ViewModel(WindowMainVM.cs). INotifyPropertyChanged is held in ObservableObject.  I have a separate Model class for the ObservableCollection called OPEmpName.cs.  I have combed Google for days and have not found a viable solution.

After the Username and Password are entered, the name of the User should appear in the TextBlock. (Demonstration Purposes Only) As it stands, the TextBlock remains blank after the method fires.  Where am I going wrong?  Thank you so much for the help!

**WindowMain.xaml**

```
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="lblUsername" Content="Username" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,57,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblPassword" Content="Password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="48,104,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtUsername" Text="{Binding Textbox1Input, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="128,60,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtPassword" Text="{Binding Textbox2Input, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="128,108,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="91,214,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding OPEmpNameList.Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    </Grid>
```

**WindowMainVM.cs**

```
public class WindowMainVM : ObservableObject
{
    private string _textbox1Input;
    private string _textbox2Input;
    private string _name;
    private int _empNum;
    private ObservableCollection<OPEmpName> _opEmpNameList;


    public String Textbox1Input
    {
        get { return _textbox1Input; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _textbox1Input, value, () => Textbox1Input); }
    }

    public String Textbox2Input
    {
        get { return _textbox2Input; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _textbox2Input, value, () => Textbox2Input);
            if (Textbox2Input != null)
            {
                fillNAME();
            }
        }
    }

    public String NAME
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _name, value, () => NAME); }
    }

    public int OPEMPNUM
    {
        get { return _empNum; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _empNum, value, () => OPEMPNUM); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<OPEmpName> OPEmpNameList
    {
        get { return _opEmpNameList; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _opEmpNameList, value, () => OPEmpNameList);
        }
    }

    public WindowMainVM() : base()
    {
        OPEmpNameList = new ObservableCollection<OPEmpName>();
    }


    private void fillNAME()
    {
        if (Textbox2Input != null)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
            {
                OPEmpNameList = new ObservableCollection<OPEmpName>();
                con.Open();
                string Query = "SELECT first_name FROM op_rep_users WHERE username='" + Textbox1Input + "' AND password='" + Textbox2Input + "' ";
                MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
                MySqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
                int count = 1;
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string Name = dr.GetString(0);
                    OPEmpName name = new OPEmpName(count, Name);
                    OPEmpNameList.Add(name);
                    count++;
                }
                con.Close();
            }

        }

    }       
}
```

**OPEmpName.cs**

```
    public class OPEmpName : ObservableObject
{
    private Int32 _count;
    private String _name;
    private ObservableCollection<OPEmpName> _opEmpNameList;


    public Int32 Count
    {
        get { return _count; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _count, value, () => Count); }
    }

    public String Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _name, value, () => Name); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<OPEmpName> OPEmpNameList
    {
        get { return _opEmpNameList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _opEmpNameList, value, () => OPEmpNameList); }
    }

    public OPEmpName() : base()
    {
        Count = 0;
        Name = "";
        OPEmpNameList = new ObservableCollection<OPEmpName>();
    }

    public OPEmpName(int count, string name) : base()
    {
        Count = count;
        Name = name;
        OPEmpNameList = new ObservableCollection<OPEmpName>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the typed username to be on the TextBlock?

Comment: Here what are you trying to do:

public class Name { public string Name {get;set} }

List<Name> list = new List<Name>() { "Name1", "Name2", "Name3" };

var howDoYouThinkWhatNameWillYouGet = list.Name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be doing a search that returns a list, but you have only one item bound to that list. You set the TextBlock to "{Binding OPEmpNameList.Name}", but OPEmpNameList is a list. You should put the results into a container like:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding OEmpNameList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Comment: It works when I use the Listbox, but not with the TextBlock suggestion.  Thoughts? Can you just not bind a member of an ObservableCollection to the TextBlock?

Comment: No, you can’t. TextBlock only binds to a single object. If your search ever returns one object, then don’t stick the results in a list.